# Why does CWE consider rand() as potentially dangerous

Tags: c++, random, cryptography

I have been using rand() function to generate random numbers. When I checked my code through a CWE check tool, It is considering rand() as a potentially dangerous function and suggesting to use crypto libraries. Can anyone please elaborate it?
What is the best and secure alternative to generate random numbers

Comment: This question has probably been already answered on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15662

Comment: The tool just isn't smart enough to analyze your code and determine whether you wrote a Hangman game or work for the NSA.  So it always complains when it sees rand().  You can get good advice here if you actually describe how you use it.

Comment: Actually that is just a unit test. I just ignored it .I would be more careful next time when coding for NSA

Answer (score 4):

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand:

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence
>   produced. In the past, some implementations of rand() have had serious
>   shortcomings in the randomness, distribution and period of the
>   sequence produced (in one well-known example, the low-order bit simply
>   alternated between 1 and 0 between calls).
>
> rand() is not recommended for serious random-number generation needs.
>   It is recommended to use C++11's random number generation facilities
>   to replace rand(). (since C++11)

Comment: The reasons that are listed in the quote are not reasons to suggest a crypto library as the CWE check tool does. So this is **not** the reason why the CWE checktool considers `rand` bad. A well seeded implementation of the Mersenne twister would have good randomness, distribution and period but it would still not be secure. And if I'm not mistaken the `mt19937` is actually used by the C++ 11's random number generation facilities.

Comment: This answer was posted before the title of the question was changed. See edit history.

Comment: That's just the title. The remaining problem is that if you replace `rand()` with your recommendation is that the code could still be vulnerable, and that there is not a single warning in your answer about that. In the worst case you've just removed the warning without removing the vulnerability.